# Write Access Violation error in C while using rand()

Tags: c

I am quite new to programming with C, so hope someone can bear with me and help me solve the issue I am facing.

I am writing a code to estimate the value of pi with Monte-Carlo method. however, when I build and debug I get an error that says:

"Exception thrown: write access violation.
a was 0x1110112.

I get this error in generate_random_array function
in this line of code:

```
a[i] = (((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) * 2.0 ) - 1.0;
```

I am posting the whole code as well for reference.

note: I am using visual studio with MSVC compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void generate_random_array(int sz, double a[]);
void count_points_inside_circle(int sz, double x[], double y[], int* counter);

int main()
{
    int tot = 1000000000;
    int incircle_c = 0;
    double  distance_sq, pi;
    double* x = NULL;
    double* y = NULL;
    

    /*create arrays in the heap*/
    x = malloc(tot * sizeof(double));
    y = malloc(tot * sizeof(double));

    /*generate random locations*/
    generate_random_array(tot, x);
    generate_random_array(tot, y);

    /*count the points inside te circle by checking the location distance*/

    count_points_inside_circle(tot, x, y, &incircle_c);

    /*estimate pi*/
    pi = 4.0 * incircle_c / (double)tot;
    
    printf("pi estimated value using %d samples was found to be %lf", tot, pi);
    
    free(x);
    free(y);
    return 0;

}

void generate_random_array(int sz, double a[]) {
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) 
        a[i] = (((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) * 2.0 ) - 1.0;

}

void count_points_inside_circle(int sz, double x[], double y[],int* counter_p) {
    int i;
    double distance_sq;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        distance_sq = x[i] * x[i] + y[i] * y[i];
        if (distance_sq <= 1)
            (*counter_p)++;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Spencer's Sixth Law](https://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html). Applies until you prove with-code that you verify both `x` and `y` successfully allocate. You're requesting  two allocations of a *billion* `double` values. That's 16gB of memory across 2x8gB chunks, which is feasible for a 64bit process; no chance in hell for a 32bit process.

Comment: This shouldn't be `rand()` related. Most likely, your allocation sizes are too big for your platform. On the other hand, you don't need an array (or allocated memory being used as an array) at all for this task.

Comment: hahaha, you are absolutely right. Thank you for your response!!

Answer (score 1):

You must always check the pointer returned from `malloc` against `NULL`. For example:

```
x = malloc(n * sizeof *x);
if (x == NULL) { /* Handle the failure and/or exit */ }
```

On the other hand, this task doesn't require use of an array (or allocated space used as an array) at all; you need only the number of points inside the circle and the number of total points generated. It could be simply done like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double estimate_pi (unsigned trial_count)
{
    const double rr = (double)RAND_MAX * RAND_MAX;
    unsigned inner_point_count = 0;
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < trial_count; ++i) {
        double x = rand();
        double y = rand();
        if (x * x + y * y <= rr)
            ++inner_point_count;
    }
    return 4.0 * inner_point_count / trial_count;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf("%f\n", estimate_pi(1000000000));

    return 0;
}
```

Note that, quality of random number generator used by the standard library significantly affects the result of this simulation.